# NSwag CodeGenerator override client class names

Tags: c#, msbuild, openapi, nswag

I create a c# client out of an openapi json using NSwag.MSBuild. In this openapi json I have a route with a hyphen in it. (something like `my-route`).

My clients are created correctly, using these settings in my nswag.json configuration.

```
...
"className": "SomeAPI{controller}Client",
"operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromFirstTagAndOperationId",
...
```

However, the generated classname for the client from the route above is `SomeAPIMy_RouteClient` with an underscore. This clashes with our coding guidelines. Is there a way to configure the code generation, so the resulting file would be `SomeAPIMyRouteClient` (without the underscore).

Comment: Does your controller or routes have underscores in?

Comment: No, they have a hyphen in it, like `my-route`

Comment: I'd suspect it's that. Classes can't have hyphens, but they can have underscores, so my guess would be its replacing them.

Comment: I'd take the symbols out of your controllers

Comment: I can't do that, I do not create and maintain them myself

Comment: Other option. Use nswag and fix the client libs yourself?